# Steady state distribution needed

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory

I have a chain $C_t$. At every instant $t$ an exponential random variable $X_t$ with parameter $\lambda$ is added to the chain or if the chain has a value greater than $Q$ then a value $Q$ is subtracted and $X_t$ is added so that the value of the chain at instant $t+1$ is $C_{t+1}=C_t+X_t-Q$ if $C_t\geq Q$ and it is $C_{t+1}=C_t+X_t$ if $C_t<Q$. I want to know if there is any steady state distribution that shows $Pr(C_t>Q)$.

I already know that the value of chain at any instant after the $Q$ is subtracted follows a steady state distribution. But I do not know if this can help in finding the above steady state distribution.

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a steady state, the long term rate of increase from the arrival variables must be equal to the rate of decrease from subtracting by $Q$, so: 
$$ E[X] = QP[C_t \geq Q] \implies P[C_t \geq Q] = \frac{E[X]}{Q} $$
You will get such a steady state if $E[X] < Q$.

---

More formally, define the indicator function $1\{C_t\geq Q\}= 1$ if $C_t\geq Q$, and 0 else. You have
$$C_{t+1} - C_t = X_t -Q1\{C_t\geq Q\}$$
Summing over $t \in \{0, 1, ..., n-1\}$ and dividing by $n$ gives: 
$$ \frac{C_n - C_0}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}X_t - Q\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1} 1\{C_t\geq Q\}$$
Suppose that $C_n/n\rightarrow 0$ with prob 1.  Then: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1} 1\{C_t \geq Q\} = \frac{E[X]}{Q} \quad (w.p.1) $$
where I have used the law of large numbers to claim that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}X_i=E[X]$ with prob 1. Finally, it can be shown (but is not obvious) $C_n/n\rightarrow 0$ with prob 1 if and only if $E[X] \leq Q$. See below for proof.

---

The proof of my $C_n/n$ claim is related to my Theorem 2.4 here ("Rate stability theorem").

http://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00271ED1V01Y201006CNT007

It is not exactly the same system, but the same trick can be used: Add a virtual process that makes the arrival rate $\epsilon$ more than the service rate.

#### Claim:

Consider the iteration $C_{t+1}=C_t + X_t - Q1\{X_t\geq Q\}$, with $\{X_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ i.i.d. with mean $E[X]$, and with $C_0=0$. Then  $C_t/t\rightarrow 0$ with prob 1 if and only if $E[X]\leq Q$.

#### Proof part 1:

Suppose $E[X]>Q$. The analysis above gives (with $C_0=0$):
\begin{align} 
\frac{C_n}{n} &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}X_t - Q\frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}1\{C_t \geq Q\} \\
&\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}X_t - Q
\end{align}
Taking a limit and using LLN gives (with prob 1): 
$$ \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{C_n}{n} \geq E[X] - Q > 0 $$
and so we conclude $C_n/n$ does *not* converge to zero with prob 1.  Further, we conclude that $C_n\rightarrow\infty$ with prob 1, meaning that after some finite time it will *always* be greater than $Q$, and so the time average service rate is *exactly* $Q$.  As in the argument from the book above, we get an exact limit: If $E[X]>Q$ then with prob 1: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{C_n}{n} = E[X] - Q $$

#### Proof part 2:

Now suppose $E[X]\leq Q$.  Fix $\epsilon>0$ and define $a = Q-E[X]+\epsilon$.  Note that $a> 0$.  Consider the *virtual process* $\tilde{C}_t$ with $\tilde{C}_0=0$ and: 
$$ \tilde{C}_{t+1}=\tilde{C}_t + X_t + a - Q1\{\tilde{C}_t\geq Q\} $$
It can be shown (by induction) that $0 \leq C_t \leq \tilde{C}_t + Q$ for all $t$. Further, by the same argument as in the proof part 1, we get with prob 1: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\tilde{C}_n}{n} = E[X]+a-Q=\epsilon $$ 
Thus: 
$$ 0 \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{C_n}{n} \leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\tilde{C}_n+Q}{n}  = \epsilon $$ 
This holds for all $\epsilon>0$ and so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} C_n/n=0$ with prob 1.

Comment: can you provide some reference for the proof of this steady state distribution. Thank you.

Comment: Which aspect? I have given you the proof itself, which I just made up.  I can give a reference similar to my last claim on $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} C_n/n$.

Comment: The reference will be great help

Comment: The claim I made on $C_n/n\rightarrow 0$ is not quite the same as the the reference I was thinking of, I will try to think if the $E[X]=Q$ case also implies $C_n/n\rightarrow 0$ if I have time.  The negative drift case $E[X]<Q$ can be treated via drift theorems such as the "Pak Lemma" in Appendix of Chapter 3, Appendix 3A.5 in _Data Networks_ by Bertsekas and Gallager (though that treats countably infintie state space): http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/datanets.html  There are likely some texts, perhaps a book by Meyn, on negative drift for uncountaby ifintely state Markov chains.

Comment: Okay I put the proof of the claim, the proof is only slightly differnet than the rate stability theorem ref.